# Vlookup equivalent in AWK scripting

Tags: awk, scripting

I have a two files and wanted to replace value in file1 from the value in file2.

File1:

```
Normal   A1
Normal   A2
Normal   A2,A3
Normal   A4
```

File2:

```
APP1      A1
APP2   A2
APP3   A3
APP4   A4
```

Expected Result:

```
Normal   APP1
Normal   APP2
Normal   APP2,APP3
Normal   APP4
```

I tried the below command but I am not getting the expected result:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$2]=$1; next};  -F "," {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ ",") $i=a[$i]; else if ($i in a) $i=a[$i]; print}' File2 File1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The one of possible **`awk`** ways:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+|,' 'NR == FNR{ a[$2] = $1; next }
     { 
         c = 0; r = $1 OFS; 
         for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
             if ($i in a) { r = r (c++? "," : "") a[$i] } 
         if (!c) r = r $2; 
         print r 
     }' file2 file1
```

The output:

```
Normal APP1
Normal APP2
Normal APP2,APP3
Normal APP4
```

Comment: Thanks, This works fine if file1 is having only two columns, but in case file1 is having more columns its only printing two columns. Sometimes File1 is having more columns in output all those columns should be there. And can you please add some explanation also in these commands